# Запуск проекта ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

При запуске проекта `ASP.NET Core Web Api` открывается браузер и пытается загрузить `/api/values` хоть этот контроллер я удалил.

Добавил в `wwwroot` файла `index.html`. Добавил этот код в `Startup`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Но при запуске проекта все равно открывается несуществующий контроллер `/api/values`. Мне нужно открывать `index.html`, либо вообще не открывать браузер. Пробовал разные варианты запуска (консоль/ISS Express).

Как изменить начальный URL, либо не открывать браузер при запуске?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, `UseMvc()` по умолчанию запрашивает ваш Values контроллер.
Установите нужный роутинг следующим образом

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=YourDefaultController}/{action=YourDefaultAction}/{id?}");
        });
```

**Upd**
Чтобы вообще не запускать браузер есть специальная галка в настройках.
Проверил - у меня отлично работает, сервер стартует и на этом все.
http://prntscr.com/iydtwy

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло.

Comment: при старте проекта у вас запускается IIS Express. посмотрите в его настройках - возможно, пока вы экспериментировали с запуском разными способами, для вашего проекта было зарегистрировано несколько виртуальных приложений (пример где посмотреть http://prntscr.com/iydqwr). 
стоит их удалить и вернутся к дефолтному варианту запуска проекта (в IIS Express с предварительно указанным URL).